# How to apply scripting effect to partial view and keep that effect in parent view as well?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I tried to apply accordion effect to partial view it works fine on partial view

index view

```
     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
    </script> 

   @{Html.RenderAction("Search1");}
```

Patial view:

```
      <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
            purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
            velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
            suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
            Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
            ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
            lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
            et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
            faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
            mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
            Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
            inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>


Controller 

      public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [Route("Search/Search1")]
        public ActionResult Search1()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Search/Search1")]
        public ActionResult Search2()
        {
            return PartialView(); 

        }
}
```

It works fine when I open  partial view directly but when I render partial view from main view
May I know what's the basic problem with it ?

Comment: Are those js and css files in the main view or partial (they should be in the main view)

Comment: I kept them at both places, still it's not working

Comment: Remove them from the partial.

Comment: Just tried, didn't work. :(

Comment: You have not shown us any of your code! (for all we know you have a typo)

Comment: Wait, I'll post code. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ It's the same code I pasted in the partial view and calling that partial from main.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchMenu(SearchViewModel svm)
        {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110202/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nil).

Comment: Updated everything now, I tried same thing into diff project as well. It doesn't work there as well.